# Psutil raises AccessDenied for all non-user-owned processes when getting process attributes

Tags: python, windows

I've bumped into a major problem: I can't access information on (most) processes that aren't owned by the user.
For example, the following:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        print proc.pid, proc.username

    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        print "denied"
```

prints:

```
0 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
4 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
428 denied
444 denied
632 my_user
648 denied
676 my_user
704 denied
748 denied
772 denied
804 denied
824 denied
832 denied
880 my_user
920 denied
988 denied
1052 denied
...
```

For these same "denied" processes methods like get_cpu_times() work fine.

**UPD:** Sorry, I ran this thing so many times with different attributes and different prints, that the output I pasted was from a different piece of code  (printed `username`, not `name`). But, I hope, the point is still clear...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the error is generated in the underlying C code.
I don't know whay [GetProcessImageFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is preferred over [QueryFullProcessImageName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (since the latter returns a path like we'd expect, using drive letters/UNC paths), but it might be that the call would fail for either one.

You'll probably have to take this up with [the developers](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/list).

From **_psutil_mswindows.c** (line 502):

```
if (GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, &exe, nSize) == 0) {
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        // see https://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/detail?id=414
        AccessDenied();
    }
    else {
        PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr(0);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I attempted to do a little more investigation of the symptoms, and I have a little more to report. On a more-or-less-fully-patched Win7 SP1 x64 machine with a relatively recent Python 2 (2.7.6), I cannot access these members of the `psutil.Process` class: `exe`, `get_ionice()`, `get_memory_maps()`, `get_nice()`, `get_cwd()`/`getcwd()`, `get_open_files()`, `name`, `nice`, and `username`.

This information is certainly available to any admin user of a Windows machine, so I don't know why psutil is failing to get it unless it's doing it in The Wrong Way™ (a perpetually moving target defined by Microsoft).

Comment: Is Python running in an elevated context?